# AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) negative effects on Alexa ranking

Tags: amp-html

As you know, custom Javascript codes are not allowed on AMP-html pages and AMP-html pages are cached somewhere on Google (AMPproject) servers.

After Google detected AMP-html on My website, I'm loosing visitors and Alexa ranking is dropping. According to Google Webmaster Tools, there is no error on these pages and they appear on search results as AMP. I using a PHP code, Google Analytics and [StatCounter](https://statcounter.com/) to measure web traffic.

So, I'm wondering if these are related or this is temporary.

Is Alexa measures traffic of AMP pages?
How can I count visitors of AMP pages?

Answer (score 0):

Alexa tracking code won't work on AMP version of your page, due to restrict to run any 3rd party JS scripts under AMP structure. So far you can only add GA to AMP page with amp-analytic component.

Answer (score 0):

The Alexa tracking code is not processed in the amp pages. You can not see in alexa's statistics the number of visits on the amp pages. However, you can retrieve the Alexa Rank by blocking Alexabot's access to the Amp pages.

```
User-agent: Alexabot
Disallow: /amp-path/
```

Comment: I removed the Italian link in your answer, as this is an English-only website.